# Automapper - map list of complex object to list of properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I have following DomainObject class:

```
public class MyDomainObj
{
   public CUSTOMER customer {get;set;} // This is database entity
   public ORDER order {get;set;}
}
```

My DTO looks like this:

```
public class MyDTO
{
   public string custId{get;set;}
   public strinf orderId{get;set;}
}
```

Let's say in `CUSTOMER` table I have an attribute with the name: `customer_id`
same for `ORDER` table its `order_id`

Here is my automapper configuration:

```
m.CreateMap<CUSTOMER, MyDTO>().ForMember(d => d.custId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.customer_id));
m.CreateMap<ORDER, MyDTO>().ForMember(d => d.orderId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.order_id));
```

I wrote an extension method for mapper in order to work:

```
public static class ExtensionAutoMapper
{
    public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(this TDestination destination, TSource source)
    {
        return Mapper.Map(source, destination);
    }
}
```

Usage is:

```
var response = Mapper.Map<MyDTO>(myDomainObj.customer)
                .Map(myDomainObj.order);
```

This works fine.

**Question:**

- How do I change my mapping configuration in order to map list of domain objects to list of dto?

something along these lines

```
var response = Mapper.Map<List<MyDomainObj>, List<MyDTO>>(myDomainObj);
```

**Edit:**
I would like to map fields in database entity to dto properties automatically if they have the same name.

Answer provided by @jmoerdyk, solve my problem. However, in that approach, I have to map all fields of a database entity to dto even if they have the same name.

Comment: If the names match, you can use [this](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/8e15798a8b4facd292feb5fcfbf1e3f7) extension for flattening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just provide the Mapping from `MyDomainObj` to `MyDto`, and it should be able to handle mapping the collections:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyDomainObj,MyDTO>()
    .ForMember(d => d.custId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.customer.customer_id))
    .ForMember(d => d.orderId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.order.order_id));
```

Then call it just like you had (assuming `myDomainObj` is a `List<MyDominObj>`):

```
var response = Mapper.Map<List<MyDomainObj>, List<MyDTO>>(myDomainObjList);
```

Comment: Let's say if there is one more column in `CUSTOMER` entity with the name `timestamp` and my `MyDTO` class also have a property with the same name, do I have to specify the mapping like given in your answer, or it will automatically get mapped?

Comment: You would still have to map it because it's not at the same depth.  The [auto-flattening convention](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) might work if you name the property on the DTO to use the conventions, which in your case would be `CUSTOMERtimestamp`.  You have to explicitly supply the mapping if your names aren't following the convention.